# Tensorflow concatenate layers not recogniing list of inputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras-layer

I am trying to create a tensorflow model using keras.Sequential() as follows:

```
nn_1 = tf.keras.Sequential() model
nn_1 = tf.keras.Sequential() model

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.concatenate([nn_1, nn_2]))
```

When I try this, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs
```

I don't understand why this is happening, since I am passing a list of 2 inputs to concatenate() . Am I missing something basic?

P.S. The same thing happened with dot() (which is what i was initially trying)